# WPF Binding.StringFormat: C vs. '{}{0:C}'

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

I am trying to globalize a simple WPF app. In several questions and/or answers on SO I see one of the following two settings on the binding:

```
StringFormat=C 
StringFormat='{}{0:C}'
```

What is the difference between these? Are there certain conditions where you would use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no difference, one is just shorthand and the other explicit. The only condition I can think of where being explicit is beneficial is when you want more control over the format. For example:

`StringFormat=Total: {0:C}`

Other than that, I'd say keep it simple; XAML is already verbose and shorthand syntax is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe read up string formatting?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

You can use {0:C} in a format string where you are filling in a value:

```
decimal value = 123.456; 
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:C2}.", value);
```

while, you use the C as a plain format:

```
Console.WriteLine(("Your account balance is " + decimal.Parse("24.3200").ToString("C"));
```

they are functionally equivalent as far as the output.  It's just a different way to format the data based on the context of how your using it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString